# Why are these strings matching my regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am still new to regular expressions and I am trying to write one that matches correct combinations of familial relationships such as great great grandmother (abbreviated GGgm)
great = `G`
step = `S`
father, mother, son, etc. = `f, m, s, d, gm, gf`

Legal: Should Match : `m, gf, Ggm, GGgf, Ss, SGgs`

Illegal: Should Not Match: `mf, Gm, SSm, GSm`

my current pattern is:

`^((m|f|d|s|gf|gm|gs|gd))|^(\S(m|f|d|s|gf|gm|gs|gd))|^(\S(G)*(gm|gs|gd|gf))|^((G)*(gf|gm|gs|gd))$`

however this is matching bad combinations such as `mf` and `Gm`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `\S(m|f|d|s|gf|gm|gs|gd)` matches `mf` for example. It looks like you should not have escaped `S`. `\S` = any non-whitespace char. Replace `\S` with `S`.

Comment: Although you might assume familial relationships are common knowledge, there are great differences between cultures around what is a 'legal' relationship (i.e. one that makes sense) and what isn't, even between English-speaking cultures there are differences. Please specify what the rules are for which you need a regex. A few examples help, but don't fully specify the rules (at least, I don't think your examples do)

Comment: Checkout https://regex101.com/ this well tell you which parts of your regular expression is matching the illegal/legal matches.

Comment: `\S` matches anything that isn't whitespace, so it will match any letter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My pattern only has issues when it comes to matching "mf" and "Gm" which is "mother father" and "Great mother". I wanted to find what part of my pattern is allowing these strings to be matched.

Comment: `\S(m|f|d|s|gf|gm|gs|gd)` matches `mf` because `\S` matches `m` and `(m|f|d|s|gf|gm|gs|gd)` matches `f`

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: What's the reason for `\S` in the patterns?

Answer (score 1):

In your regex, `\S(m|f|d|s|gf|gm|gs|gd)` matches any non-whitespace char (with `\S`) and then `m`, `f`, `d`, etc. You probably wanted to match `S` with `\S`, but that is not what `\S` does.

You can use

```
^S?(g?|G*g)[mfds]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C9d1su/2).  *Details*:

- `^`- start of string
- `S?` - an optional `S`
- `(g?|G*g)` - an optional `g` or zero or more `G` and then a `g` char
- `[mfds]` - `m`, `f`, `d` or `s`
- `$` - end of string.